# Understanding CTR in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, search-results

I've got a site that's showing a 9% CTR for a phrase in Google Webmaster Tools, but the average position for my site is 14th (this includes 7 local results for this phrase).

I was a little confused as to what the CTR actually meant, is it :

- for each person who searches for that phrase 9% of them click my site.

or

- for each person who actually sees my site in the search results 9% of them click through (bearing in mind 14th is high on page 2 when the local listings are used).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CTR is always a calculation of clicks divided by actual impressions of your link. The Webmaster Tools [help page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35252) says the same, so the last statement would be true.

Answer (score 1):

Google [personalize](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=54041) search results. So it could be that for the exact same phrase your webpage sometimes comes on page 1 and sometimes on page 2. Therefore it is possible to still get a relatively high 9% CTR and average position of 14th.